# Is it possible to share a complex object with NamespaceProxy and BaseManager without locking?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

Edit:

I've managed to "delete" one of the locks, however it's still slow. Does someone know where the ther locks are?

```
class NoLock:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, foo=None, bar=None, baz=None):
        pass

BaseManager._mutex = NoLock()
BaseProxy._mutex = NoLock()
```

I know that for multiprocessing array there is an option for `lock=False`, but is it possible to do the same for a complex object? For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 1000
    def get_a(self):
        return self._a

class SharedFoo(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__getattr__', '__setattr__', '__init__', 'get_a')
    def get_a(self):
        callmethod = object.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('get_a', ())
        
class FooManager(BaseManager):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    FooManager.register('SharedFoo', Foo, SharedFoo)
    with FooManager() as manager:
        for i in range(1000000):
            a = foo.get_a()
    processes = []
```

running `foo.get_a()` 1000000 times takes a couple of seconds which is way too slow (I would likely have to access it billions of times in the actual program). Apparently this is caused by a acquiring and releasing a lock, so is it possible to manage the lock manually so that I can make the program lock only when using certain functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just came across your question (better late than never). First, I don't believe the code you presented runs: there is no definition for `foo`. I also don't believe that there is locking on a function level as the following demonstrates. I have modified method `get_a` to (1) print out a starting message with the thread id that is currently executing, (2) sleep for 2 seconds, (3) print out an ending message with the current thread id and (4) finally return its value. I have created a processing pool of 2 processes and submitted a `SharedFoo` instance named `foo` two times in parallel to a worker function that is calling method `get_a`. The start and ending messages along with the total elapsed time clearly indicate that the calls to `get_a` do not single-thread through the method:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from threading import get_ident
import time

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 1000
    def get_a(self):
        print(f'started {get_ident()}')
        time.sleep(2)
        print(f'ended {get_ident()}')
        return self._a

class SharedFoo(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__getattr__', '__setattr__', '__init__', 'get_a')
    def get_a(self):
        callmethod = object.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('get_a', ())

class FooManager(BaseManager):
    pass


def worker(foo):
    return foo.get_a()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FooManager.register('SharedFoo', Foo, SharedFoo)
    with FooManager() as manager:
        foo = manager.SharedFoo()
        pool = Pool(2)
        t = time.time()
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(foo,))
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(foo,))
        # Wait for tasks to complete:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(time.time() - t)
```

Prints:

```
started 22320
started 36068
ended 22320
ended 36068
2.1460039615631104
```

**Proxying itself is just slow.**